# How to delete non duplicate rows in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to display the ssn, first name (fname), last name (lname), dependent name, dependent sex, and dependent relationship for all employees who have more than one dependent.
I am able to get the list of all the dependents.What is the query to display entries with more than one dependent?

SHOW CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE

```
Employee | CREATE TABLE `employee` (
`fname` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
`minit` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`lname` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
`ssn` char(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`bdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
`address` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`sex` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`salary` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`superssn` char(9) DEFAULT NULL,
`dno` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ssn`),
KEY `fk_employee_department` (`dno`),
KEY `fk_employee_employee` (`superssn`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_employee_department` 
           FOREIGN KEY (`dno`) REFERENCES `department` (`dnumber`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_employee_employee` 
           FOREIGN KEY (`superssn`) REFERENCES `employee` (`ssn`)
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

SHOW CREATE TABLE DEPENDENT

```
    DEPENDENT | CREATE TABLE `dependent` (
 `essn` char(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `dependent_name` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `sex` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `bdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `relationship` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`essn`,`dependent_name`),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_dependent_employee` 
             FOREIGN KEY (`essn`) REFERENCES `employee` (`ssn`)
 ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Currently using the query:

```
select e. ssn,e.fname,e.lname,d.dependent_name,d.sex,d.relationship 
from dependent AS d ,Employee as e
WHERE e.ssn=d.essn
```

Comment: We cannot help very effectively without knowing anything about your table structure. I assume there are at least two tables involved here, or a parent-child relationship in one table. Post more info about your tables, please.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski:I am using two tables(Employee and Dependent).I am trying to get the Employees with more than dependent using ssn...however i am getting all employees with dependents.

Comment: your title is "delete..." seem like not match your question content..sorry if I misunderstand..

Comment: Still more information is needed to know how the Employee and Dependent tables are related. Please post the results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE Employee; SHOW CREATE TABLE Dependent;`

Comment: This is the query that i am using::: select e. ssn,e.fname,e.lname,d.dependent_name,d.sex,d.relationship from dependent AS d ,Employee as e WHERE e.ssn=d.essn;

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski:I have posted the results of SHOW CREATE TABLE Employee; SHOW CREATE TABLE Dependent;

Comment: That looks like both are the `Employee` structure, not `Dependent`.

Comment: Sorry...I have edited the post now @MichaelBerkowski

Comment: Be very careful with your data.  You are storing an unencrypted ssn in combination with name and address.  This is not something that is generally not recommended (and in some cases not allowed). This is a no-no if this data is online at all but not recommended regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery to count the number of dependents for each subquery and join it in.  This will get the filter you want:

```
select e.ssn, e.fname, e.lname, d.dependent_name, d.sex, d.relationship 
from Employee e join
     dependent d 
     on e.ssn = d.essn join
     (select d.essn, count(*) as cnt
      from dependent d
      group by d.essn
      having cnt >= 2
     ) d2
     on e.ssn = d2.essn
order by e.ssn;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but i am getting an error Unknown column d.essn in the field list